# How do I get SonarQube to analyse Code Smells in unit tests but not count them for coverage reports?

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, metrics, software-quality

I have C++ project being analysed with the commercial SonarQube plugin.

My project has, in my mind, an artificially high code coverage percentage reported as both the "production" source code lines and Unit Test code lines are counted.  It is quite difficult to write many unit test code lines that are not run as a part of the unit testing, so they give an immediate boost to the coverage reports.

Is it possible to have the Unit Test code still analysed for Code Smells but not have it count towards the test coverage metric?

I have tried setting the `sonar.tests=./Tests` parameter (where ./Tests is the directory with my test code.  This seems to exclude the test code from all analysis, leaving smells undetected.  I would rather check that the test code is of good quality than hope it is obeying the rules applied to the project.

I tried adding the `sonar.test.inclusions=./Tests/*` in combination with the above.  However, I either got the file path syntax incorrect or setting this variable causes a complete omission of the Test code, so that it no longer appears under the 'Code' tab at all as well as being excluded.

The [documentation on **Narrowing the Focus** of what is analysed](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) is not all the clear on what the expected behaviour is, at least to me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as going through every permutation will be quite confusing.

Perhaps I should just accept the idea that with ~300 lines of "production" code and 900 lines of stubs, mocks and unit tests a value of 75% test coverage could mean running 0 lines of "production" code.  I checked and currently, my very simple application is at about that ratio of test code to "production" code.  I'd expect the ratio to move more towards 50:50 over time but it might not do.

Comment: Very interesting question. Which code coverage framework are you using? I understand JaCoco works quite well with SonarQube

Comment: @RannLifshitz I am using `lcov` with `genhtlm` and I have also tried `gcov`.  JaCoco is Java only is it not?

Comment: JaCoco is Java only: https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/index.html
I'll try to find a C++ equivalent. And this is what I googled : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/VBqOihjluME

Comment: @RannLifshitz I do have code coverage reports working.  It is limiting SonarQube's interpretation of what is test code and what is production code that I was having trouble with.  Granted a framework might handle that, but then I would have to make sure the framework could cope with the CppUTest Unit Test framework I am currently using for the tests themselves too.

Comment: I'll need to look into this more thoroughly. If you wish to contact me offline I will send you my email.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to have two separate SonarQube projects for a single repository.  The first you setup in the normal way, with the test code excluded via `sonar.tests=./Tests`.  The second you make a *-test* repository where you exclude all your production code.

This adds some admin and setup but guarantees that coverage for the normal project is a percentage of only the production code and that you have SonarQube Analysis performed on all your test code (which can also have coverage tracked and would be expected to be very high).

I struggle to remember where I found this suggestion a long time ago.  Possibly somewhere in the [SonarQube Community Forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/), which is worth a look if you are stuck on something.