# Sonarcloud coverage includes tests

Tags: azure-devops, sonarcloud

I have a python project and a pipeline where I run tests and send info to sonarcloud. The issue is that Coverage gate includes my test folders which lowers the total value. How do I fix it?

My folder structure, I want only `SonarTestProject/SonarTestProject` without `SonarTestProject/SonarTestProject/tests` to be covered

- SonarTestProject

  - sonar-project.properties
  - test_results
  - run_tests.cmd
  - SonarTestProject

    - api

      - utils.py
      - sql.py
    - mail.py
    - tests

      - test_api

        - test_utils.py
        - test_sql.py
      - test_mail.py

How I generate my coverage report:

```
python -m pytest SonarTestProject\tests -m "%filter%" --junitxml=tests_results\test_results.xml --cov --cov-report=xml:tests_results\coverage.xml --cov-branch --suppress-tests-failed-exit-code || exit /B 2
```

My pipeline SonarCloud step:

```
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: 'SonarCloud - abc'
    organization: 'abc-company'
    scannerMode: CLI
    configMode: manual
    cliProjectKey: 'SonarTestProject-2023'
    cliProjectName: 'SonarTestProject'
    extraProperties: |
     sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/tests_results/coverage.xml
```

I tried combinations of the properties below from this link https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/analysis-scope/. I usually get `can't be indexed twice` or it shows the same result or it's even worse like completely showing every gate as green.

```
sonar.sources = 
sonar.tests = 
sonar.test.inclusions = 
sonar.exclusions =
```

Screenshots of my issue, I know for a fact that coverage should be around 65%:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please test the following combination of settings and inform the result inside Sonar coverage report?

```
sonar.sources = SonarTestProject/
sonar.exclusions = SonarTestProject/SonarTestProject/tests/**/*.py
```

Parameters edited to the ones that worked.

Comment: Thanks!
At first, it returned an error "The folder 'SonarTestProject/SonarTestProject' does not exist for 'SonarTestProject-2023' (base directory = E:\repos\SonarTestProject)". 
I removed the first folder to make it look like this - "sonar.sources = SonarTestProject/" and it works. 
I am gonna put it as solved but I now see that code smells, security etc do not check the tests. Is there a way to not include them in coverage gate but into others?

Comment: @VitaminC never tried to cover the tests itself, but looking for this question I found this one here and maybe it's the same thing that you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516502/how-do-i-get-sonarqube-to-analyse-code-smells-in-unit-tests-but-not-count-them-f

Comment: Hmmm, "sonar.coverage.exclusions = SonarTestProject/tests/**/*.py" seems to work exactly as I want. For reference, I thought that I don't need a specific glob pattern ie "**/*.py", I thought that just the name of the folder would exclude everything within which was not the case.